# Как я могу анимировать текст SVG, чтобы он постепенно появлялся

Tags: javascript, css, svg

Я пытаюсь анимировать SVG, как если бы он был записан, [как в этом примере на Codepen.](https://codepen.io/tigercodes/pen/bGWmQRV)
И как я могу сделать свою собственную SVG-анимацию (например, в коде приведенном ниже) такими же, как в Codepen?
(Помимо замены идентификатора пути!)

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="417.773" height="224.047" viewBox="0 0 417.773 224.047">
  <path id="Path_35" data-name="Path 35" d="M-3.875-234.323c-1.516,0-8.928,23.415-22.236,70.078-2.021.842-29.143,6.907-81.533,18.193-.505,0-.842-.674-1.348-2.021.842-1.179,6.57-22.742,16.846-64.687,0-.842-.505-1.179-1.348-1.348h-1.348c-1.179,0-7.581,22.91-18.867,68.73q-8.844,3.285-95.01,23.584c-35.881,7.917-53.906,12.3-53.906,13.477v2.021a4.017,4.017,0,0,1,2.021.674q56.1-14.15,143.525-33.691c0,.505.168.674.674.674h.674q0,1.516-23.584,92.988a4.017,4.017,0,0,1,.674,2.021h2.7l25.605-96.357c10.276-3.538,37.566-9.6,81.533-18.193h.674q-17.435,69.236-33.691,141.5c.674,1.853,1.348,2.7,2.021,2.7h.674l1.348-.674c11.624-53.738,23.415-101.916,35.039-144.873,38.408-8.591,66.035-12.8,82.881-12.8h5.391l3.369,3.369h.674c.674,0,1.348-.842,2.021-2.7,0-3.2-3.2-4.717-9.434-4.717h-.674c-15.5,0-42.451,3.875-80.859,11.455,0-.505-.505-.674-1.348-.674,2.7-11.624,9.265-33.86,19.541-66.709,0-1.348-.505-2.021-1.348-2.021Zm14.993,93.662c-8.254,0-13.982,6.738-17.519,20.215,0,6.57,4.548,10.276,13.477,11.455,9.434,0,19.036-7.917,28.975-23.584,0-1.348-.505-2.021-1.348-2.021H33.354c-8.76,13.477-16.677,20.215-23.584,20.215H2.358a7.891,7.891,0,0,1-4.043-4.043v-2.021a26.887,26.887,0,0,1,1.348-6.064c11.624-3.706,17.519-6.57,17.519-8.76v-2.021a5.721,5.721,0,0,0-5.391-3.369Zm-8.591,9.939c1.516-3.2,3.369-4.885,5.559-5.222l3.369-.168-4.717,2.864ZM98.716-238.029c-1.516,0-3.875,6.738-7.412,20.215q-4.3,20.973-34.365,78.838c-8.254,14.319-13.645,21.562-16.172,21.562H38.745c-1.853-.505-2.7-2.527-2.7-6.064v-10.107c14.487-43.63,24.089-76.311,28.975-97.7-.337-3.2-1.011-4.717-2.021-4.717H60.981l-4.043,4.043c-17.014,44.978-25.605,79.006-25.605,101.748v4.043c0,7.581,2.527,12.129,7.412,13.477,7.581,0,20.215-18.025,37.734-53.906h.674c-3.538,17.183-5.391,29.817-5.391,37.734v4.043c0,6.233,1.516,10.276,4.717,12.129h2.7c4.548,0,11.624-7.244,21.562-21.562-.505,0-.674-.505-.674-1.348H98.042C88.1-123.479,81.533-117.414,78.5-117.414c-1.348-.337-2.021-2.19-2.021-5.391v-4.717c0-12.971,3.2-31.838,9.434-56.6,10.276-31,15.5-48.347,15.5-51.885,0-1.348-.505-2.021-1.348-2.021Zm-41.1,17.519v.674c-2.19,11.118-6.738,26.448-13.477,45.82h-.674v-.674c0-5.054,4.548-20.383,13.477-45.82ZM106.3-139.482c-6.57,0-11.118,6.738-13.477,20.215,0,6.233,2.864,9.939,8.76,11.455,4.548,0,8.928-4.043,13.477-12.129,14.319-5.391,22.4-9.939,24.258-13.477v-.674c0-.842-.505-1.179-1.348-1.348h-1.348c-8.591,5.9-14.656,8.76-18.193,8.76h-.674C116.909-135.271,113.035-139.482,106.3-139.482Zm-1.348,5.391c3.875-1.516,6.57.168,8.086,5.391v2.021q-6.822,0-8.086-6.064Zm-4.717,5.391c4.885,3.706,8.423,5.9,10.781,6.738-2.021,5.9-4.885,8.76-8.76,8.76h-2.021c-1.348-.674-2.19-2.358-2.7-5.222C97.2-121.12,98.042-124.49,100.232-128.7Zm51.211,7.244c-4.043,0-7.075,2.19-8.928,6.738l3.032,2.864c5.728-1.685,8.928-3.538,9.6-5.728-.168-2.527-.842-3.875-1.685-3.875Z" transform="translate(262.624 238.029)" fill="#949ba5"/>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How can I animate SVG text to be “written out”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68825379/7394871) от участника  [@Kai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15763239/kai).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/68825379/7394871

Answer (score 4):

> И как я могу сделать свою собственную SVG-анимацию (например, в коде
> приведенном ниже) такими же, как в Codepen?

Для этого вам нужно изменить свой SVG

Ваша фигура нарисована двойными контурами

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо перерисовать фигуру с помощью одинарных контуров и сделать линию толще (`stroke-width="6"`)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что получилось:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 417.8 224" height="224" width="417.8">
<g fill="none" stroke="#949BA5" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round">
   <!-- Length = 337px -->
<path id="horizont"  d="M3.8 130l82.4-20 60.3-13.8L213.7 81l56.2-11 25-4.2s21.7-3 32.5-2c3.3.3 5 3 5 3"/> 
  
<path id="vert1" d="M169.1 24l-15 55.5-10.5 41.6-17.8 70" />
<path id="vert2" d="M259.3 5.8l-7.8 23.7L241 63.2l-8.6 33.2L220 148l-11.5 49.8-5.3 22.6" />
<path id="sign" d="M259.8 110.4s6-1.4 10.3-3.4c2.8-1.3 6.8-2 6.8-4.9 0-1.5-2-2.6-3.5-2.7-3.4-.4-7 1.6-9.3 4.1-3.6 4-5.7 10.2-5 15.6.4 2.5 2 5 4.3 6.2 3.2 1.7 7.4 1.3 11 .4 5-1.4 9.7-4.3 13.3-8.1 5.8-6.2 8.5-14.8 11.7-22.6 2.7-6.8 4-14 6.3-20.9 2.2-6.8 7.2-20.4 7.2-20.4l7.3-25s2.8-8.8 3.6-13.4c.7-3.6 4.6-9.9 1-11-3.4-1.2-4 6-5.5 9.3-3 6.1-7 19.3-7 19.3l-5.7 17.4-5.2 22.2-4.4 19a54.5 54.5 0 00-1.4 20.6c.5 3.6 2.3 9.7 3.8 10.3 2 .7 4.2 1 6.2-.7 3.4-3 6.3-6.5 9-10.2 4.5-6.4 8-13.5 11.7-20.3 3-5.3 6-10.7 8.7-16l7.6-15.1L354 32.5s4-13.3 6.2-20c1.9-6.8 4.2-13 1.3-11-3.3 6.2-4.9 15.6-6.9 22.1-2.1 7-11.3 41.8-11.3 41.8l-4.2 22.3-2.2 19.8s-.7 7.2.2 10.7c.5 1.9 1 4.6 3 5.1 3 .9 6.1-2.4 8.3-4.4 2.5-2.3 7-7.2 7-7.2s3.6-5 6.5-6.8c3.3-2-2.8 6.3-3.4 9.7-.5 3-1.5 6.5 0 9.1 1.2 2.2 3.9 4.1 6.4 4 3.5 0 6.5-3.1 8.7-5.8 2.4-3 4.2-6.7 4.5-10.5.2-2.2-.2-4.7-1.6-6.4-1.8-2.3-4.9-4.2-7.8-4-2.6.2-6.2 2-6.4 4.5-.2 2.4 3.2 3.7 5.1 5 2.3 1.6 5 3 7.7 3.3 3 .5 6.2-.2 9.2-1a42 42 0 0015.8-8.6" />
<path id="dot" d="M407 123c0-2 2.7-3.6 4-4.2 1.6-.8 2.2-.7 4-1 1 0 1.4 2 1 3-.2.7-2.9 1.7-1.8 1.3 0 0-4 2.6-5.9 2.4-.7 0-1.4-.8-1.4-1.5z" />
</g>
</svg>
```

Анимируем один элемент с помощью `stroke-dashoffset`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 417.8 224" height="224" width="417.8" style="background:#151515">
<g fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round">
   <!-- Length = 750px -->
<path id="Sign" stroke-dashoffset="750" stroke-dasharray="750" d="M259.8 110.4s6-1.4 10.3-3.4c2.8-1.3 6.8-2 6.8-4.9 0-1.5-2-2.6-3.5-2.7-3.4-.4-7 1.6-9.3 4.1-3.6 4-5.7 10.2-5 15.6.4 2.5 2 5 4.3 6.2 3.2 1.7 7.4 1.3 11 .4 5-1.4 9.7-4.3 13.3-8.1 5.8-6.2 8.5-14.8 11.7-22.6 2.7-6.8 4-14 6.3-20.9 2.2-6.8 7.2-20.4 7.2-20.4l7.3-25s2.8-8.8 3.6-13.4c.7-3.6 4.6-9.9 1-11-3.4-1.2-4 6-5.5 9.3-3 6.1-7 19.3-7 19.3l-5.7 17.4-5.2 22.2-4.4 19a54.5 54.5 0 00-1.4 20.6c.5 3.6 2.3 9.7 3.8 10.3 2 .7 4.2 1 6.2-.7 3.4-3 6.3-6.5 9-10.2 4.5-6.4 8-13.5 11.7-20.3 3-5.3 6-10.7 8.7-16l7.6-15.1L354 32.5s4-13.3 6.2-20c1.9-6.8 4.2-13 1.3-11-3.3 6.2-4.9 15.6-6.9 22.1-2.1 7-11.3 41.8-11.3 41.8l-4.2 22.3-2.2 19.8s-.7 7.2.2 10.7c.5 1.9 1 4.6 3 5.1 3 .9 6.1-2.4 8.3-4.4 2.5-2.3 7-7.2 7-7.2s3.6-5 6.5-6.8c3.3-2-2.8 6.3-3.4 9.7-.5 3-1.5 6.5 0 9.1 1.2 2.2 3.9 4.1 6.4 4 3.5 0 6.5-3.1 8.7-5.8 2.4-3 4.2-6.7 4.5-10.5.2-2.2-.2-4.7-1.6-6.4-1.8-2.3-4.9-4.2-7.8-4-2.6.2-6.2 2-6.4 4.5-.2 2.4 3.2 3.7 5.1 5 2.3 1.6 5 3 7.7 3.3 3 .5 6.2-.2 9.2-1a42 42 0 0015.8-8.6" >
    <animate id="anSign"
    attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
    begin="0s;anSign.end+1s"
    dur="3s"
    values="750;0"
    repeatCount="1"
    fill="freeze" />
</path>   
</svg>
```

Анимируем все элементы фигуры

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 417.8 224" height="224" width="417.8" style="background:#151515">
<g fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round">
   <!-- Length = 337px -->
<path id="Horizont" stroke-dashoffset="337" stroke-dasharray="337"  d="M3.8 130l82.4-20 60.3-13.8L213.7 81l56.2-11 25-4.2s21.7-3 32.5-2c3.3.3 5 3 5 3"> 
   <animate id="anHorizont" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="anVert1.end+0.25s" dur="0.3s" values="337;0" fill="freeze"/>
</path> 
                   <!-- Length = 173px -->
<path id="Vert1" stroke-dashoffset="173" stroke-dasharray="173"  d="M169.1 24l-15 55.5-10.5 41.6-17.8 70" >
    <animate id="anVert1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="anVert2.end+0.25s" dur="0.25s" values="173;0" fill="freeze" />
</path>  
                   <!-- Length = 232px -->
<path id="Vert2" stroke-dashoffset="232" stroke-dasharray="232" d="M259.3 5.8l-7.8 23.7L241 63.2l-8.6 33.2L220 148l-11.5 49.8-5.3 22.6"> 
     <animate id="anVert2"  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="anSign.end+0.25s" dur="0.25s" values="232;0" fill="freeze" />
</path>  
   
     <!-- Length = 750px -->
<path id="Sign" stroke-dashoffset="750" stroke-dasharray="750" d="M259.8 110.4s6-1.4 10.3-3.4c2.8-1.3 6.8-2 6.8-4.9 0-1.5-2-2.6-3.5-2.7-3.4-.4-7 1.6-9.3 4.1-3.6 4-5.7 10.2-5 15.6.4 2.5 2 5 4.3 6.2 3.2 1.7 7.4 1.3 11 .4 5-1.4 9.7-4.3 13.3-8.1 5.8-6.2 8.5-14.8 11.7-22.6 2.7-6.8 4-14 6.3-20.9 2.2-6.8 7.2-20.4 7.2-20.4l7.3-25s2.8-8.8 3.6-13.4c.7-3.6 4.6-9.9 1-11-3.4-1.2-4 6-5.5 9.3-3 6.1-7 19.3-7 19.3l-5.7 17.4-5.2 22.2-4.4 19a54.5 54.5 0 00-1.4 20.6c.5 3.6 2.3 9.7 3.8 10.3 2 .7 4.2 1 6.2-.7 3.4-3 6.3-6.5 9-10.2 4.5-6.4 8-13.5 11.7-20.3 3-5.3 6-10.7 8.7-16l7.6-15.1L354 32.5s4-13.3 6.2-20c1.9-6.8 4.2-13 1.3-11-3.3 6.2-4.9 15.6-6.9 22.1-2.1 7-11.3 41.8-11.3 41.8l-4.2 22.3-2.2 19.8s-.7 7.2.2 10.7c.5 1.9 1 4.6 3 5.1 3 .9 6.1-2.4 8.3-4.4 2.5-2.3 7-7.2 7-7.2s3.6-5 6.5-6.8c3.3-2-2.8 6.3-3.4 9.7-.5 3-1.5 6.5 0 9.1 1.2 2.2 3.9 4.1 6.4 4 3.5 0 6.5-3.1 8.7-5.8 2.4-3 4.2-6.7 4.5-10.5.2-2.2-.2-4.7-1.6-6.4-1.8-2.3-4.9-4.2-7.8-4-2.6.2-6.2 2-6.4 4.5-.2 2.4 3.2 3.7 5.1 5 2.3 1.6 5 3 7.7 3.3 3 .5 6.2-.2 9.2-1a42 42 0 0015.8-8.6" >
    <animate id="anSign" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="0s" dur="2s" values="750;0" fill="freeze" />
</path>   
    
<path id="Dot" stroke-width="4" stroke-dashoffset="25" stroke-dasharray="25" d="M407 123c0-2 2.7-3.6 4-4.2 1.6-.8 2.2-.7 4-1 1 0 1.4 2 1 3-.2.7-2.9 1.7-1.8 1.3 0 0-4 2.6-5.9 2.4-.7 0-1.4-.8-1.4-1.5z" >
      <animate id="anDot"  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="anSign.end+0.2s" dur="0.25s" values="25;0" fill="freeze" />
</path>   
</g>
</svg>
```

Вариант цветовой схемы как в вопросе

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 417.8 224" height="224" width="417.8">
<g fill="none" stroke="#949BA5" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round">
   <!-- Length = 337px -->
<path id="Horizont" stroke-dashoffset="337" stroke-dasharray="337"  d="M3.8 130l82.4-20 60.3-13.8L213.7 81l56.2-11 25-4.2s21.7-3 32.5-2c3.3.3 5 3 5 3"> 
   <animate id="anHorizont" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="anVert1.end+0.25s" dur="0.3s" values="337;0" fill="freeze"/>
</path> 
                   <!-- Length = 173px -->
<path id="Vert1" stroke-dashoffset="173" stroke-dasharray="173"  d="M169.1 24l-15 55.5-10.5 41.6-17.8 70" >
    <animate id="anVert1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="anVert2.end+0.25s" dur="0.25s" values="173;0" fill="freeze" />
</path>  
                   <!-- Length = 232px -->
<path id="Vert2" stroke-dashoffset="232" stroke-dasharray="232" d="M259.3 5.8l-7.8 23.7L241 63.2l-8.6 33.2L220 148l-11.5 49.8-5.3 22.6"> 
     <animate id="anVert2"  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="anSign.end+0.25s" dur="0.25s" values="232;0" fill="freeze" />
</path>  
   
      <!-- Length = 750px -->
<path id="Sign" stroke-dashoffset="750" stroke-dasharray="750" d="M259.8 110.4s6-1.4 10.3-3.4c2.8-1.3 6.8-2 6.8-4.9 0-1.5-2-2.6-3.5-2.7-3.4-.4-7 1.6-9.3 4.1-3.6 4-5.7 10.2-5 15.6.4 2.5 2 5 4.3 6.2 3.2 1.7 7.4 1.3 11 .4 5-1.4 9.7-4.3 13.3-8.1 5.8-6.2 8.5-14.8 11.7-22.6 2.7-6.8 4-14 6.3-20.9 2.2-6.8 7.2-20.4 7.2-20.4l7.3-25s2.8-8.8 3.6-13.4c.7-3.6 4.6-9.9 1-11-3.4-1.2-4 6-5.5 9.3-3 6.1-7 19.3-7 19.3l-5.7 17.4-5.2 22.2-4.4 19a54.5 54.5 0 00-1.4 20.6c.5 3.6 2.3 9.7 3.8 10.3 2 .7 4.2 1 6.2-.7 3.4-3 6.3-6.5 9-10.2 4.5-6.4 8-13.5 11.7-20.3 3-5.3 6-10.7 8.7-16l7.6-15.1L354 32.5s4-13.3 6.2-20c1.9-6.8 4.2-13 1.3-11-3.3 6.2-4.9 15.6-6.9 22.1-2.1 7-11.3 41.8-11.3 41.8l-4.2 22.3-2.2 19.8s-.7 7.2.2 10.7c.5 1.9 1 4.6 3 5.1 3 .9 6.1-2.4 8.3-4.4 2.5-2.3 7-7.2 7-7.2s3.6-5 6.5-6.8c3.3-2-2.8 6.3-3.4 9.7-.5 3-1.5 6.5 0 9.1 1.2 2.2 3.9 4.1 6.4 4 3.5 0 6.5-3.1 8.7-5.8 2.4-3 4.2-6.7 4.5-10.5.2-2.2-.2-4.7-1.6-6.4-1.8-2.3-4.9-4.2-7.8-4-2.6.2-6.2 2-6.4 4.5-.2 2.4 3.2 3.7 5.1 5 2.3 1.6 5 3 7.7 3.3 3 .5 6.2-.2 9.2-1a42 42 0 0015.8-8.6" >
    <animate id="anSign" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="0s" dur="2s" values="750;0" fill="freeze" />
</path>   
    
<path id="Dot" stroke-width="6" stroke-dashoffset="25" stroke-dasharray="25" d="M407 123c0-2 2.7-3.6 4-4.2 1.6-.8 2.2-.7 4-1 1 0 1.4 2 1 3-.2.7-2.9 1.7-1.8 1.3 0 0-4 2.6-5.9 2.4-.7 0-1.4-.8-1.4-1.5z" >
      <animate id="anDot"  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="anSign.end+0.2s" dur="0.25s" values="25;0" fill="freeze" />
</path>   
</g>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68839534/7394871) от участника  [@Alexandr_TT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7394871/alexandr-tt).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Путь отрисовывается на canvas отдельными линиями по точкам, полученным из SVG-path методом `getPointAtLength()`. Canvas находится поверх SVG, положение и размеры выставляются единожны согласно размерам и позиции SVG.

Для корректировки координат получаются данные viewbox:

```
    const dx = +viewbox[0]; // Начальное смещение по Х
    const dy = +viewbox[1]; // Начальное смещение по Y
    const k = box.width/viewbox[2]; // Соотношение к реальному размеру
```

Что в дальнейшем позволяет подправлять каждую точку:

```
(points[i].x-dx)*k, (points[i].y-dy)*k
```

Сам SVG-путь "текста" не менялся, со всеми его переходами между отдельными отрезками пути. Можно "распарсить" путь на отдельные куски по "m" или по "z" и передавать в функцию массив отдельных путей. Тогда переходов не будет.

```js
const svg = document.querySelector('svg');
const path = svg.querySelector('path');
const viewbox = svg.getAttribute('viewBox').split(' ');

const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const box = svg.getBoundingClientRect();
canvas.style.top = box.y + 'px';
canvas.style.left = box.x + 'px';
const w = canvas.width = box.width;
const h = canvas.height = box.height;

const dx = +viewbox[0];
const dy = +viewbox[1];
const k = box.width/viewbox[2];

const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillRect(0,0,w,h);
ctx.strokeStyle = 'yellow';

drawPath(1000);

function drawPath(steps){
    const len = path.getTotalLength();
    const step = len/steps;
    const points = [];
    
    for(let i=0; i < steps; i++){
        points.push(path.getPointAtLength(step*i));
    }
    
    let pi=0;
    
    draw();
    
    function draw(){
        ctx.stroke(new Path2D(`M ${(points[pi].x-dx)*k} ${(points[pi].y-dy)*k} L ${(points[pi+1].x-dx)*k} ${(points[pi+1].y-dy)*k}`));
        pi++;
        
        const frame = requestAnimationFrame(draw);
        if(pi === points.length-1){
            cancelAnimationFrame(frame);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-270 -240 430 230" height="250">
    <path d="M-3.875-234.323c-1.516,0-8.928,23.415-22.236,70.078-2.021.842-29.143,6.907-81.533,18.193-.505,0-.842-.674-1.348-2.021.842-1.179,6.57-22.742,16.846-64.687,0-.842-.505-1.179-1.348-1.348h-1.348c-1.179,0-7.581,22.91-18.867,68.73q-8.844,3.285-95.01,23.584c-35.881,7.917-53.906,12.3-53.906,13.477v2.021a4.017,4.017,0,0,1,2.021.674q56.1-14.15,143.525-33.691c0,.505.168.674.674.674h.674q0,1.516-23.584,92.988a4.017,4.017,0,0,1,.674,2.021h2.7l25.605-96.357c10.276-3.538,37.566-9.6,81.533-18.193h.674q-17.435,69.236-33.691,141.5c.674,1.853,1.348,2.7,2.021,2.7h.674l1.348-.674c11.624-53.738,23.415-101.916,35.039-144.873,38.408-8.591,66.035-12.8,82.881-12.8h5.391l3.369,3.369h.674c.674,0,1.348-.842,2.021-2.7,0-3.2-3.2-4.717-9.434-4.717h-.674c-15.5,0-42.451,3.875-80.859,11.455,0-.505-.505-.674-1.348-.674,2.7-11.624,9.265-33.86,19.541-66.709,0-1.348-.505-2.021-1.348-2.021Zm14.993,93.662c-8.254,0-13.982,6.738-17.519,20.215,0,6.57,4.548,10.276,13.477,11.455,9.434,0,19.036-7.917,28.975-23.584,0-1.348-.505-2.021-1.348-2.021H33.354c-8.76,13.477-16.677,20.215-23.584,20.215H2.358a7.891,7.891,0,0,1-4.043-4.043v-2.021a26.887,26.887,0,0,1,1.348-6.064c11.624-3.706,17.519-6.57,17.519-8.76v-2.021a5.721,5.721,0,0,0-5.391-3.369Zm-8.591,9.939c1.516-3.2,3.369-4.885,5.559-5.222l3.369-.168-4.717,2.864ZM98.716-238.029c-1.516,0-3.875,6.738-7.412,20.215q-4.3,20.973-34.365,78.838c-8.254,14.319-13.645,21.562-16.172,21.562H38.745c-1.853-.505-2.7-2.527-2.7-6.064v-10.107c14.487-43.63,24.089-76.311,28.975-97.7-.337-3.2-1.011-4.717-2.021-4.717H60.981l-4.043,4.043c-17.014,44.978-25.605,79.006-25.605,101.748v4.043c0,7.581,2.527,12.129,7.412,13.477,7.581,0,20.215-18.025,37.734-53.906h.674c-3.538,17.183-5.391,29.817-5.391,37.734v4.043c0,6.233,1.516,10.276,4.717,12.129h2.7c4.548,0,11.624-7.244,21.562-21.562-.505,0-.674-.505-.674-1.348H98.042C88.1-123.479,81.533-117.414,78.5-117.414c-1.348-.337-2.021-2.19-2.021-5.391v-4.717c0-12.971,3.2-31.838,9.434-56.6,10.276-31,15.5-48.347,15.5-51.885,0-1.348-.505-2.021-1.348-2.021Zm-41.1,17.519v.674c-2.19,11.118-6.738,26.448-13.477,45.82h-.674v-.674c0-5.054,4.548-20.383,13.477-45.82ZM106.3-139.482c-6.57,0-11.118,6.738-13.477,20.215,0,6.233,2.864,9.939,8.76,11.455,4.548,0,8.928-4.043,13.477-12.129,14.319-5.391,22.4-9.939,24.258-13.477v-.674c0-.842-.505-1.179-1.348-1.348h-1.348c-8.591,5.9-14.656,8.76-18.193,8.76h-.674C116.909-135.271,113.035-139.482,106.3-139.482Zm-1.348,5.391c3.875-1.516,6.57.168,8.086,5.391v2.021q-6.822,0-8.086-6.064Zm-4.717,5.391c4.885,3.706,8.423,5.9,10.781,6.738-2.021,5.9-4.885,8.76-8.76,8.76h-2.021c-1.348-.674-2.19-2.358-2.7-5.222C97.2-121.12,98.042-124.49,100.232-128.7Zm51.211,7.244c-4.043,0-7.075,2.19-8.928,6.738l3.032,2.864c5.728-1.685,8.928-3.538,9.6-5.728-.168-2.527-.842-3.875-1.685-3.875Z" fill="#949ba5"/>
  </svg>
  <canvas style="position:absolute"></canvas>
```

Comment: Добавил атрибут height для SVG для того, чтобы лучше влезал в малое окно просмотра, но его можно и убрать. Правда при изменении "На всю страницу" размеры Холста уже не перестраиваются, хотя можно и это сделать, но тогда либо анимации надо начинать сначала, либо вводить новый коэффициент для уже нового размера Холста. И по ходу отрисовки менять по сути координаты точек.

Comment: решение интересное и подойдет возможно для других задач, но  на мой взгляд, не для решения этого вопроса. ТС привел ссылку на codepen, где показано, как он хочет, чтобы выглядела анимация. То есть должна быть анимирована одинарная, толстая линия  Поэтому только плюс.

Comment: Я в принципе ничего хорошего не жду))) Просто хотел попробовать этот метод. Вначале вообще хотел вроде шпионской проявки сделать: штрихи по дуге водить туда-сюда, а в месте пересечения с текстом, чтобы проявлялось каким-то цветом, но не зашло пока. Никак не смог я поженить здесь SVG и canvas. А что касается того, чего хочет автор, то тут просто надо в редакторе исправлять изначальный путь, а чисто программно изменить его вряд ли получится, во всяком случае это уже будет тема друго диссертации)) Поэтому особого смысла в этом не вижу - воспользовался путем именно автора вопроса. Прошу прощения.

Comment: ты прав, нужно изменять путь в векторном редакторе на одинарный. Цель моего ответа в картинках, была донести до новичков в SVG, что нужно **сразу рисовать правильно** - одинарным контуром, тогда не будет проблем с анимацией.  Двойные контуры, показывающие толщину линий, возникают при конвертировании из растра или при рисовании кистью, надо ведь, как-то показать толщину линий. Что ты описал в начале предыдущего комментария, это реализуется анимацией маски вдоль path c шириной строки превышающей самую толстую часть текста  [Пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/817777/28748)